# declare type in TypeScript based on the return type of a generator function

Tags: typescript, react-redux, typescript-typings

This is how i define an action using an ActionCreater and its Type.

```
   const listRequestAction = new ActionCreator<undefined, undefined>(
        REQUEST_LIST
      );
    
   type listRequestActionType = ReturnType<
        typeof listRequestAction.create
        >;
```

I wanted to add a dynamic namespace to my actions so I made this change to the action.

```
       const listRequestAction = (namespace: string) => 
          new ActionCreator<undefined, undefined>(
            `${namespace}${REQUEST_LIST}`
          );
```

how do i redefine listRequestActionType to support the namespace change?

Comment: Please share reproducable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible in TS 4.2 and higher. (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEEkGdQFwCwJbXgU1AYwPYCdsvTKHgGYp4B26KA-KHDDAA6QBcIA5gvAK4BGAdFgC2wdAEMhZTOSFjIAaxTA8YggFo8AE24APNTACejFJHTYEjGACh0AGznQAggQTSAwipg4APABUANKAACgB8oADeVqDRRChimtK2BrBGKCygvgDcVlExWOSQMNjcBDgAFIbG6b4AlBGwiJD8lWgAvCnGmaAAvrnRZnEwbaBljGIGtpjx6UF1rWFl4R1pDUjNqYFjE1OaPTXZvTkgEKAO3JKgAAYASgCiAIoAqrcAyr4A%20gAy4G%20XoEinUCFczkdgYaSFMTkGDUGwQwh3J6vD7fN7pABEiOeby%20P186NA7UxD2xKLx6JycIKhFsSBg1xQAEduCYYM4YK5yITQN4goEAHISExjKigFA6IbkTTQYEIUEhMp9UDkIWQEUrQWSNWqFBKmrpdmcjyDHyXAAk4U1wp13QtLUwxFAWORuLe3UugVChJCSpiypQAHdQIb3J5yr6-TFzeEVVr1bbws6cajfO7TtBo1btVQE-bHUmyW7LhHojUci1QLTCgzmayQ%20RfKleQLVeqxRKUFKZUU5ewwu0GTBuNgG02lfXjWIvNhvJnWza7akHU6SS6U%207PSEANrogZTlDogC6VhCmSAA). Seems a bit verbose, though. Feel free to refactor it.

```
// Is this the correct reference? https://github.com/cameronmaske/react-redux-typescript
class ActionCreator<T, P> {
    readonly type: T;

    constructor(type: T) { this.type = type; }
    create = (payload: P) => ({ type: this.type, payload });
}


// I assume `REQUEST_LIST` is a string constant?
const REQUEST_LIST: "REQUEST_LIST" = "REQUEST_LIST"


const listRequestAction = <P, Namespace extends string>(
    namespace: Namespace
    ): ActionCreator<`${Namespace}${typeof REQUEST_LIST}`, P> =>
        new ActionCreator(
            `${namespace}${REQUEST_LIST}` as `${Namespace}${typeof REQUEST_LIST}`
        )

type listRequestActionType<P, Namespace extends string> = ReturnType<
    ActionCreator<`${Namespace}${typeof REQUEST_LIST}`, P>["create"]
>;
```